# Preg_replace content in brackets

Tags: php, regex, api, parsing, preg-replace

I'm parsing the wikipedia API and the API responces in the following format:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing [[elitaaa|elit]], sed do eiu
smod tempor incididunt ut labore et. Ut [[enim (enimaaddasd)|enima]] ad 
minim veniam, [[some realllllly long word|quis]]  [[ullamco|test]] laboris 
iquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit 
in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
```

My goal is to replace every "[[long|word]]" with just "word". For example the first line should look like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiu
```

I don't care about the content of the "long" ( it may contain all characters, spaces and `()` ), I just need to replace the content in brackets with "word".

I did the following regex:

```
$data = preg_replace(
            '/\[\[([\s\S])\|(.*?)\]\]/',
       '$2', $data);
```

But sometimes it's matching whole paragraphs, for example it replaces

```
adipisicing [[elitaaa|elit]], sed do eiu smod tempor incididunt ut labore et.
Ut [[enim (enimaaddasd)|enima]] ad
```

with `adipisicing enima ad`.. I tried to add `{1,20}` after `[\s\S]`, but it's not effective, because the content in "long" can be a whole sentence or just single 5 char word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\[\[[^\]]+\|([^\]]+)\]\]/', '$1', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
<?php
$str = <<<STR
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing [[elitaaa|elit]], sed do eiu
smod tempor incididunt ut labore et. Ut [[enim (enimaaddasd)|enima]] ad 
minim veniam, [[some realllllly long word|quis]]  [[ullamco|test]] laboris 
iquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit 
in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
STR;

$res = preg_replace('/\[+[^\]]+\|([^\]]+)\]+/', '$1', $str);
echo $res;
?>
```

Regular expression:

```
\[+         match '[' (1 or more times)
  [^\]]+    any character except: '\]' (1 or more times)
  \|        match literal '|'
  (         group and capture to \1:
   [^\]]+   any character except: '\]' (1 or more times)
  )         end of \1
   \]+      match ']' (1 or more times)
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiu
smod tempor incididunt ut labore et. Ut enima ad 
minim veniam, quis  test laboris 
iquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit 
in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was bored so I gave a procedural example a go. If not for you then it may be of interest to others who find this page.

There is no guarantee that it is bug-free (it works for the example string, though), and I wanted to handle tags that are not closed/opened, as well, but I have to run.

```
$s = 'First, we begin with a [[single]] word. Next, we use an [[pseudonym|alias]]. ';
$s.= "And then a [[tag with\na newline]] in it. That [[is]] it!";

function wiki_parse($input) {
    $output = '';
    $offset = 0;
    while (true) {
        $open  = mb_strpos($input, '[[', $offset);
        $close = mb_strpos($input, ']]', $offset);
        if ($open === false or $close === false)
            break;
        if ($open > $offset)
            $output .= mb_substr($input, $offset, $open-$offset);
        $output .= wiki_parse_token($input, $open, $close);
        $offset = $close+2;
    }
    if ($offset < mb_strlen($input))
        $output .= mb_substr($input, $offset);
    return $output;
}

function wiki_parse_token($input, $open, $close) {
    $token = mb_substr($input, $open+2, ($close-$open)-2);
    if (mb_strpos($token, "\n") !== false) {
        $token = "[[$token]]";
    } else {
        $sep = mb_strpos($token, '|');
        if ($sep !== false) {
            $token = mb_substr($token, $sep+1);
        }
    }
    return $token;
}

var_dump($s);
var_dump(wiki_parse($s));
die;
```